# Born U.B but mostly known as

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

The goal is to come up with an answer with the help of the image below.
Together with the title, they should lead to the correct answer.

[image]

Hint1

> There are **two** different type of problems here. The portion above 'sometimes' and the portion below 'sometimes'. Together, they should guide you in the right direction.

Hint2

> For the top portion, think in terms of quadrants.

Comment: I think U.B has something to do with Usain Bolt.

Comment: No, nothing to do with Bolt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Partial Answer**

I think the ultimate answer is

> [Pope Gregory XIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Gregory_XIII)

Who was born as

> **Ugo Boncompagni** (initials U.B.)

The grid

> If we highlight the diagonals in each quadrant as indicated by the right-angle triangles ($\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ indicates that we are looking the hypotenuses of each triangle) then we get the following
>  [image]
>  Reading from the left side and going clockwise, the first grid reads
>  **BISHOP OF ROME**
>  which is another name for the Pope. The initials grid reads
>  **JFMAMJJASOND**
>  which are the initials of the months of the Gregorian calendar, in order, the calendar introduced by Pope Gregory XIII

Bottom image

> I can only think that the cross refers to Easter and the [computus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus) (calculation of the date of Easter). There are calendar based algorithms which change depending on whether we use the Julian or Gregorian calendar so this would hint at the symbols on the cross. Also, the "+1" might indicate the presence of a leap year (hence the meaning of "sometimes").
>  This part is not fully formulated which is why I've marked as Partial Answer.

Comment: Nice job :) For the bottom image rot13(jung vs gur "pebff" npghnyyl ercerfragrq n fcrpvsvp glcr bs hasbyqrq phor?)

Comment: So yes you were right about the +1